# Como hostear una aplicacion de angular dentro del folder que contiene Wordpress

Tags: angular, wordpress, web

Tengo una pagina principal en Wordpress pero a la vez tengo un directorio llamado proyectos en donde tengo varias aplicaciones en JavaScript. Pero ahora tengo una aplicación hecha en Angular pero cada vez que esta en una ruta dentro de la app y se recarga la pagina manda error 404 en Wordpress.

Un ejemplo seria:

La ruta raiz de la aplicacion de angular seria

`pagina-ejemplo.com/proyectos/angular-app/`

Y una de las rutas seria

`pagina-ejemplo.com/proyectos/angular-app/ruta1`

Cuando yo recargo (F5) en esta ruta en vez de mostrarme la aplicacion de angular me muestra el error 404 pero no del servidor si no de Wordpress.

La estructura del archivos que tengo en el servidor donde tengo hosteado Wordpress es esta.

```
\-|
  |-- proyectos
  |-- wp-admin
  |-- wp-content
  |-- wp-includes
```

Trate de cambiar el .htaccess pero todavia no encuentro la solución.

De antemano muchas gracias por leer.

Answer (score 0):

La solución que encontré fue reescribiendo en el `.htaccess`

Tuve que agregar este código.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /proyectos/angular-app/
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Lo que tuve que buscar es como hacer un deploy de una aplicación en angular en una subcarpeta, para que esto funcione en tienes que reemplazar el `/proyectos/angular-app/` por la carpeta en donde tengas tu aplicación de angular y listo!

Si por ejemplo tu carpeta en donde esta tu proyecto se llama **gatitos** lo que tienes que hacer es en vez de poner `RewriteBase /proyectos/angular-app/` poner `RewriteBase /gatitos/`

Espero que ayude :)